# CQ/AEM extjs get selection dropdown box text, and get page path

Tags: extjs, dialog, selection, aem

Say I have a component with dialog drop to parsys on a content page `/content/phonegap/ss/en_gb/login/home/test1/jcr:content/par/productimage`

now inside the dialog i have something like [image]

I wish to get `$PATH` append to URL and send selected device e.g the text `'Device ID:HTC_10_GOLD'`, to servlet in this dialog listener extjs:

```
<deviceAndColour
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
        fieldLabel="Device and Colour"
        name="./deviceAndColour"
        options="/bin/reference/data/device.devices.json$PATH"
        type="select"
        xtype="selection">
    <listeners
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            selectionchanged="function(pathfield) {
                var selected = this.findParentByType('form').find('name', './deviceAndColour')[0].getText();
                console.log( this.findParentByType('form').find('name', './deviceAndColour')[0].getText());
                $.getJSON('/bin/reference/data/device/availablecolour.availablecolour.json$PATH?selectedDevice=' + selected + '&colour=red', function(jsonData){
                    selectBox.setOptions(jsonData);
                });
            }" />
</deviceAndColour>
```

So bascially, the `console.log( this.findParentByType('form').find('name', './deviceAndColour')[0].getText());` is not working as I expected, neither the `$PATH` inside the dialog listener js, it does not retrieve the path at all.

Apart from above attempt, I know `var selected = this.findParentByType('form').find('name', './deviceAndColour')[0].getValue();` this will get the value asscociated with the select correctly, but I do not need value, I just wish to `getText()`, and get the current `$PATH` in extjs.

another questions, you may noticed `$.getJSON('/bin/reference/data/device/availablecolour.availablecolour.json$PATH?selectedDevice=' + selected + '&colour=red'`

how do I skip the &  in this listner,  as if i use & directly, project won't even build. there must be someway to skip & and let extjs treat as part of the string to send request

Anyone expereinced this before? please suggest with code example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the **text of the option** selected:

```
function(field,value){
    for(var i = 0; i < field.options.length; i++) {
        if(field.options[i].value === value) {
            console.log('Selected: ' + field.options[i].text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the **path to the resource** being edited:

```
function(field,value){
    console.log("Resource:" + field.findParentByType("dialog").path);
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection

**UPDATE**

Please try the following code adapted to your scenario (I also refactored the code to make use of `params` when providing query parameters. There is no reason why this shouldn't work.

```
function(field, value) {
    var selected = '';
    var path = field.findParentByType("dialog").path;

    // get text of option selected
    for(var i = 0; i < field.options.length; i++) {
        if(field.options[i].value === value) {
            selected = field.options[i].text;
            break;
        }
    }

    var params = {
        selectedDevice: selected,
        colour: 'red'
    }

    $.getJSON('/bin/reference/data/device/availablecolour.availablecolour.json'+path, params, function(jsonData){
        // FIXME: how are you getting the "selectBox" reference?
        selectBox.setOptions(jsonData);
    });
}
```

Comment: the 2nd part getting path of resource working 100% fine :)  but the 1st part doesn't get the selected text, any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: @seph did you modify your handler function to take two parameters instead of one? i.e. `function(pathfield, value)`

Comment: hi mick, yes I did,  i think the problem may be... it is not hardcode options in dialog.xml,  instead, it is actually when user clicks dropdown box, dialog calls servlet, then servlet returns a bunch of data ,then dialog render the options list.  so when the dialog was 1st initalized before calling servlet, there is no options with the selectbox at all....   could that be the problem? am i m talking silly...

Comment: please have a look at my updated answer. Note: I would recommend that you do not pass the option label to your servlet but pass the value instead (option labels are only meant for the UI)